# Unity Javascript anim/collision not working the way I hoped

Tags: javascript, animation, unity-game-engine, collision

I have an animation of an arm picking something up and I wanted to combine that with a collision. So if the animation was playing and the arm touched the game object COIN it would remove the coin. Here is what I have now

```
    #pragma strict
var anim: Animation;

function Update() {
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
    anim = GetComponent.<Animation>();
    anim.Play(anim.clip.name);
    }
}


function OnCollisionEnter (col : Collision)
{
if(!anim.IsPlaying(anim.clip.name)){
    if(col.gameObject.name == "prop_powerCube"){
          Destroy(col.gameObject);
         }
    }
}
```

I am trying to actually finish something with value this time on unity and I would appreciate any help given.

EDIT: i legit forgot to tell whats wrong, it tries to get animation from "prop_powerCube" instead of the variable anim.clip.name
error:

MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "prop_powerCube" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "prop_powerCube". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
Money Add.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Money Add.js:7)

~Thank you!!!!

Comment: So what's the problem? You put a code without describing the problem

Comment: I don't think that bump with comment work on website. It does when you edit your question or provide new answer. I want to let you know that your chances of getting answer about Unity reduces when you use Javascript instead of C#. What is the name of GameObject the `Animation` component is attached to?

Comment: Alright you've convinced me. I tried to stay away from C# because it looked difficult but I'll trash this idea as I haven't made it very far and have a go at it. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You are welcome. Start from [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting)